# Cordova Phonegap-Facebook-Plugin searches for plugin in the wrong folder from where CLI Installed it

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I'm trying to install the cordova Facebook plugin, Phonegap-Facebook-Plugin, but am having some issues and I'm disoriented because I don't understand how Cordova plugins work in general, so any light anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

I have installed the plugin using the following line as indicated on the ReadMe:

```
cordova -d plugin add /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

I have the correct plugin information in my config.xml:

```
<plugin name="FacebookConnectPlugin" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
<access origin="https://m.facebook.com" />
<access origin="https://graph.facebook.com" />
<access origin="https://api.facebook.com" />
<access origin="https://*.fbcdn.net" />
<access origin="https://*.akamaihd.net" />
```

And I have the correct plugin information in the Info.plist in the ios folder:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>** my app id **</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>>** my app name **</string>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>**fb + my app id ** </string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
```

However when I go to build this with the Ionic build process, I get the following error:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/path/to/my/app/platforms/ios/goodMood/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookConnectPlugin.m'
```

And indeed there IS no such file or directory, because this directory seems to have been put, by the Cordova CLI, in the following directory:

```
/path/to/my/app/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect
```

Which means this problem is essentially the opposite of the issue opened here:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/601

Any ideas on how I can reconcile this seemingly very straight-forward problem???

Comment: Try this plugin it should work (http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.ccsoft.plugin.cordovafacebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a plugin from a url too. Re-create your Cordova project like this:

```
cordova create YOUR_APP_NAME
cd YOUR_APP_NAME
cordova platform add ios android
cordova -d plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
cordova build
```

Comment: Yep, starting from scratch solved things for me although I'm at a loss as to why! I'm saying it has something to do with the names or initializing, because I think the previous project might have been copied over from another directory? Can't even remember!